# Contract's address format specification

Tags: protocol, encoding, address

Is there a specification somewhere which explains how to compute a human-readable address of a contract?

In order to originate a contract I need to provide its code, initial storage value and some other data and then I'll get its address. How is it computed?

Answer (score 4):

When your originate a contract, you send an "operation" to the network. This operation is then serialized into byte format and a hash is derived - this is the operation hash for the given operation.

If an operation generates a new contract, you can manually calculate the new KT1 address by hashing the operation hash + an index byte (starting from 0). We use an index as some operations originate multiple new KT1 addresses. This is how eztz does it: https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L751

I'm unsure why you need this though - you don't need to know the new address before originating?

Comment: Thanks. So it's only possible to compute address of originated contract, right? I am asking because I am writing an interpreter of Michelson and there is `ADDRESS` instruction. It always returns address of a contract (not `option` value). Does it imply that it's impossible to put a contract on stack if this contract hasn't been originated?

I made an experiment using `./alphanet.sh client run script`. I computed address of `SELF` and `PACK`ed. Then passed those bytes to another script and succesfully `UNPACK`ed them. But this contract is not originated. How does it work?

Comment: Also which operations can originate multiple KT1 addresses? I found the following operations in the spec: `CREATE_CONTRACT`, `CREATE_ACCOUNT`, `TRANSFER_TOKENS` and `SET_DELEGATE`. As far as I understand, the first one originates 1 KT1 address and other operations don't generate KT1 addresses at all.

Comment: Also which hashing algorithm is used? Is it blake2b both times?